# 3D orbit outside of Blender

Tags: 3d-view, export, .fbx, obj

Hoping someone can help me. Can anyone advise on how i could create a 3D model in Blender, but then orbit and zoom etc around it outside of Blender.

I work for a company that makes Web Based Trainings, and as part of them, I want the option to have a 3D model that the user can look around, instead of using a video.

Is there something like this, even as html that i can insert into the WBTs?

Many thanks

Comment: I think you can upload your models to sketchfab and then embed the 3d viewer on any website

Comment: Ah, yes. I have just looked and I think that may work. Thank you